# BigQuery: insert table to an existing Google analytics with sharded table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an existing dataset (A) in bigquery with ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD (sharded by date) which is populating every day through google analytics.
What I wanted to do is to insert data from a different dataset (B) with the same schema.
So for example, I have ga_sessions_20200120 and onwards, and I would like to insert data with dates ga_sessions_20191201, 20191202 from the dataset (B). How do I achieve this? Since the ga_sessions_20191201 table doesn't exist in my dataset (A)?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to move your tables from the dataset B to the dataset A?

Comment: I want to copy only the tables that don't exist in the dataset A.

Comment: How many tables do you have to copy? Are there too many to simply do a few `CREATE  TABLE` queries?

Comment: I have at least 3 months of tables with ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD

Comment: Then I would do this with a BigQuery Data Transfer Service dataset copy job, it can sync datasets and only copy across tables that don;t existing in the destination table, sounds like exactly what you need? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets

Comment: I dont see any option to filter out the table I can copy, it seems it will either copy the entire dataset tables into the new one or overwrite the existing one, which isn't the case for me. I only need xx date to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy only some specif date tables from the dataset_b to the dataset_a, you can use the `bq` command inside a `Bash` script just like below

```
d="20170708"
until [[ $d > 20170720 ]];
    do bq cp <dataset_b>.ga_sessions_$d <dataset_a>.ga_sessions_$s;
    d=$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```

This script will iterate the dates starting from the date you define in the `d` variable, until the date you define inside the `until` clause.
In each iteration, the bq command will copy the ga_sessions table for that date from a dataset to another.

UPDATE:

If you want to copy your tables based on conditions involving its fields, you can use `bq query` setting a destination table for your query's results:

```
date="20170708"
until [[ $date > 20170720 ]];
    do
    sql="SELECT "*" FROM <dataset_b>.ga_$date WHERE <your_condition>"
    dest="<dataset_a>.ga_sessions_${date}"
    bq query --destination_table $dest -n=0 --use_legacy_sql=false "$sql";
    date=$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d "$date + 1 day")
done
```

Comment: is it possible to add a WHERE condition there?

Comment: What exactly do you want do to?

Comment: I have dataset A that contains data from ga_sessions_20191201 to ga_sessions_20200223 that I want to copy to dataset B that has missing data in those date range that Dataset A has. However, I need to filter out the data in dataset A using hostname filter.

Comment: You want to filter it based in a field of the table?

Comment: yes that is correct. Filter is one of the fields in ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: since the ga-session table from analytics is nested, if i unnest it, the column will not match?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: because in bigquery. if i want to use the hostname filter for example, it's under the hits, so i need to do select * from <dataset_b>.ga_$date, unnest(hits) as h WHERE h.page.hostname='www.test.com' will this work?

Comment: In this case, if you want only the original data filtered you could do something like select g.* from <dataset_b>.ga_$date as g, unnest(hits) as h WHERE h.page.hostname='www.test.com'

Comment: i tried running the script above and i encountered error, Syntax error: Unexpected floating point literal "114XXXXXX." Where 114XXXXXX. is my dataset.  Code is here: ```#!/bin/bash
date="20181214"
until [[ $date > 20181216 ]];
    do
    sql="SELECT g.* FROM 1XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_$date as g, unnest(hits) as h  WHERE h.page.hostname='www.test.com'"
    dest="XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_${date}"
    bq query --destination_table $dest -n=0 --use_legacy_sql=false "$sql";
    date=$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d "$date + 1 day")
done
```